# How to install Ionic v1? Following official guides install v2

Tags: ionic-framework

I have followed the [installation guide for ionic v1](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html) but running
ionic start projectname blank

```
creates Ionic v2 app.
```

From current version docs I found

> Once that’s done, create your first Ionic app:
>
> $ ionic start cutePuppyPics
>
> Add –v1 if you’d like to use Ionic 1

However I can not understand where should this v1 be added.  Tried diffenent places but always get an error or v2 run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use command:

```
ionic start myApp blank --v1
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer results in ERROR stating --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed so now the command will be as

```
ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to install like ionic1 or ionic2. After installing node.js and cordova open node.js command prompt and follow this syntax.

ionic start (your app name) (category of app) --type ionic1 or ionic2

For example: if you want to create a sidemenu app in ionic1 then follow this syntax.

ionic start myApp sidemenu --type ionic1

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
ionic start myApp blank --type=ionic1
```